# mysql join two really complex queries

Tags: mysql, join

I currently have two really complex queries that I use to bring in scores with ranks.  The first is all the participants and their scores with stage ranks, the second is Grouped by each participant and calculates their overall rank (sum of stage ranks).

First query to get all participants for each stage with scores and ranks

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT alias, catabbr, sh_dq, raw, sdq, dnf, 
@rownum := IF(@stage != stage_name, 1, @rownum + 1) AS rowNum,
@rank := IF(@prevVal != cTime, @rownum, @rank) AS rank,
@stage := stage_name as stage_name,
@prevVal := cTime AS cTime,
id, zeroTime
  FROM 
(SELECT @rownum:= 0) rn,
(SELECT @rank:= 1) av,
(SELECT @stage:= '') sv,
(SELECT @prevVal:= 0) pv,
(SELECT s.stage_name stage_name, sc.alias alias, sc.catAbbr catabbr, sc.sh_dq sh_dq, sc.time raw, sc.id id, sc.sdq sdq, sc.dnf dnf, 
    IF(sc.time = "0", 1, 0) AS zeroTime,
    ((ROUND(sc.time, 2) + (sc.miss * 5)) + ((sc.proc * 10) + (sc.saf * 10) + (sc.sog * 30)) - (sc.bthPoints)) cTime
    FROM matches m
    LEFT JOIN stages s ON s.match_id = m.id
    LEFT JOIN scores sc ON sc.stage_id = s.id
    WHERE m.matchuuid = 'E13A4C61-A2B8-48E2-BE1B-1FFB77CC5849'
    GROUP BY sc.alias, s.stage_name
    ORDER BY s.stage_name, zeroTime, cTime
) tv
) t
ORDER BY zeroTime, alias, stage_name;
```

Outputs:

```
+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------+-----+-----+--------+------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
| alias     | catabbr | sh_dq | raw             | sdq | dnf | rowNum | rank | stage_name            | cTime | zeroTime |
+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------+-----+-----+--------+------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
| Back Bob  | S       | 0     | 52.9799995422   | 0   | 1   | 54     | 54   | Stage 1               | 92.98 | 0        |
+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------+-----+-----+--------+------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
| Back Bob  | S       | 0     | 43.9099998474   | 0   | 0   | 46     | 46   | Stage 2               | 48.91 | 0        |
+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------+-----+-----+--------+------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
| Ben Scal  | ES      | 0     | 26.9699993134   | 0   | 0   | 27     | 27   | Stage 1               | 31.97 | 0        |
+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------+-----+-----+--------+------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
| Ben Scal  | ES      | 0     | 32.8800010681   | 0   | 0   | 38     | 38   | Stage 2               | 42.88 | 0        |
+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------+-----+-----+--------+------+-----------------------+-------+----------+
```

Second query groups participants by name and sums their ranks for a final rank

```
SELECT alias, catabbr, SUM(cTime) fTime, SUM(rank) fRank, zeroTime, rank
FROM (
  SELECT alias, catabbr, sh_dq, raw, sdq, dnf, 
@rownum := IF(@stage != stage_name, 1, @rownum + 1) AS rowNum,
@rank := IF(@prevVal != cTime, @rownum, @rank) AS rank,
@stage := stage_name as stage_name,
@prevVal := cTime AS cTime,
id, zeroTime
  FROM 
(SELECT @rownum:= 0) rn,
(SELECT @rank:= 1) av,
(SELECT @stage:= '') sv,
(SELECT @prevVal:= 0) pv,
(SELECT s.stage_name stage_name, sc.alias alias, sc.catAbbr catabbr, sc.sh_dq sh_dq, sc.time raw, sc.id id, sc.sdq sdq, sc.dnf dnf, 
    IF(sc.time = "0", 1, 0) AS zeroTime,
    ((ROUND(sc.time, 2) + (sc.miss * 5)) + ((sc.proc * 10) + (sc.saf * 10) + (sc.sog * 30)) - (sc.bthPoints)) cTime
    FROM matches m
    LEFT JOIN stages s ON s.match_id = m.id
    LEFT JOIN scores sc ON sc.stage_id = s.id
    WHERE m.matchuuid = 'E13A4C61-A2B8-48E2-BE1B-1FFB77CC5849'
    GROUP BY sc.alias, s.stage_name
    ORDER BY s.stage_name, zeroTime, cTime
) tv
) t
GROUP BY alias
ORDER BY zeroTime, fRank, fTime;
```

Outputs:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| alias     | catabbr   | fTime     | fRank | zeroTime  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| Back Bob  | S         | 141.89    | 100   | 0         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| Ben Scal  | ES        | 74.85     | 68    | 0         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

The zeroTime column makes it so I can sort by times that are greater than 0, and correctly calculate the rank.

When I try to join them I get no results or anything. Is there a way to combine/join these two queries into one query so that they will output the following?

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| alias     | catabbr   | fTime     | fRank | zeroTime  | Stage 1 Time  | Stage 1 Rank  | Stage 2 Time  | Stage 2 Rank  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Ben Scal  | ES        | 74.85     | 68    | 0         | 31.97         | 27            | 42.88         | 38            |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Back Bob  | S         | 141.89    | 100   | 0         | 92.98         | 54            | 48.91         | 46            |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

This will be going into a php page, so I can loop through and pull in what I need, the main thing I'm trying to do is join these two queries.

My structures and data are too big for a sqlfiddle.
Here is the structure and inserts for matches and stages: http://pastebin.com/YvZevd5j
Here is the structure and inserts for scores: http://pastebin.com/jLBYxMvc

One thing to note too, is that a game could have 1 or more stages and 1 or more particpants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Answer may not scale well as you would need to know the number of stages, but perhaps you can handle building it with a loop or something in you application. Here's a simplified version, you can modify it to work with your data.

```
SELECT 
  alias,
  catAbbr,
  sum(fTime) as fTime,
  sum(fRank) as fRank,
  sum(zeroTime) as zeroTime,
  sum(Stage_1_Time) as stage_1_Time,
  sum(Stage_1_Rank) as Stage_1_Rank,
  sum(Stage_2_Time) as stage_2_Time,
  sum(Stage_2_Rank) as Stage_2_Rank
FROM (
  SELECT 
    alias,
    catAbbr,
    0 as fTime,
    0 as fRank,
    0 as zeroTime,
    Stage_1_Time as stage_1_Time,
    Stage_1_Rank as Stage_1_Rank,
    0 as stage_2_Time,
    0 as Stage_2_Rank
  FROM (query that gets stage 1 info)
  UNION
  SELECT
    alias,
    catAbbr,
    0 as fTime,
    0 as fRank,
    0 as zeroTime,
    0 as stage_1_Time,
    0 as Stage_1_Rank,
    stage_2_Time as stage_2_Time,
    Stage_2_Rank as Stage_2_Rank
  FROM (query that gets stage 2 info)
  UNION
  SELECT
    alias,
    catAbbr,
    fTime as fTime,
    fRank as fRank,
    zeroTime as zeroTime,
    0 as stage_1_Time,
    0 as Stage_1_Rank,
    0 as stage_2_Time,
    0 as Stage_2_Rank
  FROM (query that gets averaged info)
) temp
GROUP BY alias, catAbbt
```

Comment: This would work if I knew before hand how many stages, but I don't so it has to be dynamic.  I've gone ahead and found a way to use both queries and merge the data via php.  Thanks for your suggestion though.